# XSLT : generate csv from xml which has multiple occurences of tags

Tags: xslt

I have a xml with format:
<

```
G>
 <P>
  <A>
    <b>value b</b>
    <c>value c</c>
   </A>
   <A>
    <b>value b2</b>
    <c>value c2</c>
   </A>
  <D>value e</D>
  <E>value f</E>
 </P>
</G>
```

There are many tags like 'A' which can occur multiple times .The problem is that if A occurs once output in CSV and thus xl sheet(where data is exported) is :

column1    column2      column3    column4 
value b    value c     value e     value f

If A comes twice  output in xl comes as

column1       column2        column3        column4  
value b        value c       value b2       value c2     value e    value f 

I want it as  
column1     column2       column3      column4  
value b     value c      value e      value f 
value b2    value c2      value e      value f

to make csv I have xslt code something like this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="G/P/A"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="D"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="E"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
```

Comment: I have assumed that you can use XSLT 2.0, and that the common column names D & E are neither fixed in name or in number. Also assuming that the regular column names are not fixed either. Let me know if otherwise is true.

Comment: Column names are fixed but number is not ,since few tags have maxOccurs="unbounded" in xsd .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you what you want, although doesn't check for your format being different to what you state

```
<xsl:for-each select="//A">
    <xsl:value-of select="b"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="c"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::P/D"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::P/E"/>
    <xsl:text>  
</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and to test for multiple lines:

```
    <G>
        <P>
            <A>
                <b>value b</b>
                <c>value c</c>
            </A>
            <A>
                <b>value b2</b>
                <c>value c2</c>
            </A>
            <D>value e</D>
            <E>value f</E>
        </P>
        <P>
            <A>
                <b>value bx</b>
                <c>value cx</c>
            </A>
            <A>
                <b>value b2x</b>
                <c>value c2x</c>
            </A>
            <D>value ex</D>
            <E>value fx</E>
        </P>
    </G>
```

gives an output of

```
value b,value c,value e,value f  
value b2,value c2,value e,value f  
value bx,value cx,value ex,value fx  
value b2x,value c2x,value ex,value fx
```

Comment: Thanks,Woody its working for above xml but in my XML I have few tags in <G> node as well ,if I have to access them as well then how will I reference them ? I used ../..(node in <G>) but it is not working correctly,is ../.. representation different from using ancestor?

Comment: ancestor::* brings back a list of nodes going up the tree, so ancestor::G will give you something in the G node. Is it in another subnode? Add an example and I can ammend the answer if you want

Comment: Its working with ancestor now ,may be I made some typo earlier , but now I have another problem if I have <b> tag in <G> as well like this   <G>
 <P>
  <A>
  .....    </A>
  <D>...</D>
  <E>.....</E>
 </P>  <X><b></b></X>
</G>   then in that case code is also displaying b in X ,I used ancestor-or-self but it did not work ,how can I refer only a particular b that I want.